# Security method javascript

Tags: javascript, security

I have a function javascript

```
var foo = new function()
{
   var c={"key":"123"};
   this.print=function()
   {
     return c.key;
   }
}
```

But on **Console** tools Firefox and Chrome. User can declare function

```
var foo=new function(){
  this.print=function()
  {
    return "Hello, You are hacked";
  }
}
```

How can i security my foo function what using for other function. Or, when user **declare foo**, Have any way **i know it was declared**

Comment: The owner of the browser, with the console and developer tools open, can run any code they want and there's nothing you can do to prevent it. The best you can do is minify and obfuscate your code to make it harder, but you really can't ever trust the client (browser) to enforce security anyway.

Comment: Thanks  Stephen P. If I wish a "event" help i know foo declared. Is it possible.

Comment: What about using a getter?